# Extensão para o chrome - Como usar a DOM no site que esta aberto

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão

Como faço para usar a DOM de uma pagina que está aberta no navegador pela o código na minha extensão?

Ex: No popup da minha extensão tem um botão, do qual espero que ao clicar, o valor de uma div no site que está aberto mude.

Tem como fazer isso? Só consigo acessar a DOM do popup da extensão, mas não consigo acessar a DOM da pagina aberta

Answer (score 0):

eu tenho uma extensão para o Chrome e eu fiz algo assim:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var btnLoginCI = createButton('Login CI');

  btnLoginCI.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('clicked'); // code here!!!
  });
});
```

Comment: Não é bem o que eu quero, aparentemente dessa forma vai criar o botão no popup da extensão e o alerta não será exibido